# I want to store json data and use it when require ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

here is the code

```
    NSString *url = @"http://somesite.com/";
    NSURL *stringURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSLog(@"url-------- %@",stringURL);
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:stringURL];
    NSLog(@"data---------%@",urlData);

    if (urlData)
    {
        // JSON successfully downloaded
        NSLog(@"yes ");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"not exist");
    }
```

when i try to print NSData i give me null and control goes to else block. correct me please.. i want to store the json data and than use it where it is needed

Comment: Have you resolved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try changing your code after the NSURL line to the following:

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:stringURL options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
    if (urlData)
    {
        // JSON successfully downloaded
        NSLog(@"yes ");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"not exist");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine. I think, you are getting an error with App Transport security.
When I ran your code, I found an error stating -

"App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file."

To fix this, go to your project's info.plist file, right click on it and select the Source Code option like this -

[image]

Then just paste

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

under the  tag. Everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

NSData will return nil if origin data is invalid format.
you can use - initWithContentsOfURL:options:error: to get error message.